# Replace fragments in Android

Tags: android, fragment

I can't replace the fragments using the codes below. I mean that the second fragment appeared under the first fragment. The first fragmnent didn't hide as I expected. What is wrong here?
Thanks a lot!

My activity :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity  {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final FragmentManager fm = this.getFragmentManager();
    final Fragment fragmenttwo = new FragmentTwo();

    Button fmchangebutton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.fmchangebutton);
    fmchangebutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

             FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
             ft.replace(R.id.fragment1, fragmenttwo);
             ft.commit();

        }

    });

    };

};
```

activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/fmchangebutton"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Change Fragment" />

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment1"
    android:name="com.example.fragementex.FragmentOne"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
 </LinearLayout>
```

fragmnetone.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="clip_horizontal"
    android:ems="10"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal|top|fill_vertical"
    android:text="This is Fragment One" >


</EditText>

</LinearLayout>
```

fragmnettwo.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="clip_horizontal"
    android:ems="10"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal|top|fill_vertical"
    android:text="This is Fragment Two" >

  </EditText>

 </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot replace a fragment attached to the layout, you need to create a host container as `FrameLayout` like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:orientation="vertical" >

      <Button
          android:id="@+id/fmchangebutton"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="Change Fragment" />

      <FrameLayout
          android:id="@+id/frame_layout"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Then, you will able to - first - `add` and display the first fragment and `replace` it with the second as follows:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // set the layout which contains the framelayout
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final FragmentManager fm = this.getFragmentManager();
    final Fragment fragmentone = new FragmentOne();
    final Fragment fragmenttwo = new FragmentTwo();

    // if first initialization
    if(savedInstanceState == null) {
        // display with "add" the first fragment
        this.getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.frame_layout, fragmentone).commit();
    }

    Button fmchangebutton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.fmchangebutton);
    fmchangebutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
            // "replace" the fragment inside the framelayout
            ft.replace(R.id.frame_layout, fragmenttwo);
            ft.commit();
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: @Rudi According to the reference: *"FrameLayout is designed to block out an area on the screen to display a single item. Generally, FrameLayout should be used to hold a single child view"* - You can use whatever ViewGroup to host a Fragment (I tested it!) but you will have strange behaviour. For example, in LinearLayout, your Fragment can be not displayed, even if the stacktrace said that it's added. FrameLayout are designed for it.

Comment: @Rudi Also, when you add a Fragment dynamically, you still have your Activity behind. So mainly, you need a ViewGroup which can make your views overlap each other. I think, that's why FrameLayout are the best choice.